# Order by date then id, not ordering by second column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm ordering an Active Record relation by a date column then an foreign key id column, but the second ordering doesn't take effect.

```
recs.order('date, parent_id')
recs.order('date asc, parent_id asc')
etc.
```

None of the expected ordering works when the first column is a date. It simply won't order the second column within date.

This orders by the date column but NOT by the parent_id column, eg:

```
01/01/2015 ParentB
01/01/2015 ParentB
01/01/2015 ParentA
01/01/2015 ParentB
20/06/2015 ParentA
...
```

You see the records are not ordered by parent_id with a date. Using Rails 4.2.3, Postgres 9. The date attribute is defined as date type in the migration, so shouldn't have a time portion.
The ordering should be:

```
01/01/2015 ParentA
01/01/2015 ParentB
01/01/2015 ParentB
01/01/2015 ParentB
20/06/2015 ParentA
...
```

(assuming ParentA is displaying for parent_id 1 and ParentB for parent_id 2)

Comment: SQL is ordering correct. the second order only appears if the first ordered value is equal. please give us some real data

Comment: The first ordered value is equal in the first 4 records, yet the second column is not being ordered

Comment: @rigyt were you able to figure out what the problem was?

Comment: I didn't, but I'm not using this code anymore and reckoned it's more likely I was doing something stupid rather than postgres. Have you encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4, you can do it like this

```
Model.order(column1: :asc, column2: :desc)
```

More from [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)

```
Client.order(orders_count: :asc, created_at: :desc)  
# OR  
Client.order(:orders_count, created_at: :desc)  
# OR  
Client.order("orders_count ASC, created_at DESC")  
# OR  
Client.order("orders_count ASC", "created_at DESC")
```

If you want to call order multiple times e.g. in different context, new order will append previous one

```
Client.order("orders_count ASC").order("created_at DESC")  
# SELECT * FROM clients ORDER BY orders_count ASC, created_at DESC
```

Comment: Same result, it won't sort the second column within a date. It works the other way around, so it's as if it doesn't think the dates are equal in value when on same day, but they are of class Date and are equal in Rails. Maybe Postgres has a different opinion

Comment: Edit your question and add the whole query, the data structure, and a representation of what you really want the result to look like.

Comment: Is your parent_id actually holding strings, like 'ParentH'?

Comment: No it's holding the integer id of the foreign key. I've updated my example data to illustrate more clearly that it's definitely not sorting by the second column

Comment: We if you are sorting by parent_id the result will be sorted by the actual integer value in the key, not by it's name...

Comment: Yes of course it should be, but it's not sorting by this column which is the problem. The example data tries to illustrate this (see how the ParentB values are not grouped within the same date 01/01/2015)

Comment: Rails and Postgresql ordering definitely works and you're using it right from what you are saying. Your problem lies in the other parts of your code which you haven't posted.